# What visual programming language works well for scripting admin tasks?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, scripting, system-administration

Would like a visual environment for creating admin scripts to manage tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows, you might try [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).  It comes with an integrated scripting environment similar to IDEs like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for when you say "visual environment" and "visual programming language"?  Are you looking for an IDE?  What parts of the IDE are important to you?  It's hard to give you an answer without understanding what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked this on a programmers site, I'm assuming that its programming related admin tasks.  Have a look at http://www.nantbuilder.com which provides a good editor for writing nant (htp://nant.sourceforge.net) scripts which in turn is a good language for automating builds...